# Saving data from a page in the local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first time asking or doing this type of question

So I created this page http://lamp.cse.fau.edu/~mcuervo5/p4/
and it does your basic to do app list thing for adding and deleting stuff.

Apparently the only thing missing is to save the data on the current page. I heard that there a code that can save the current page to a local storage that has everything already in it, so when I re-open the link, instead of having nothing in the "complete and incomplete" list, it should look like this [image: Screenshot]

thanks, it the only part I have left to do & I dont know if it implemented in HTMl or Jquery. I do not know how to do it.

and if you want to see the code here instead of "inspect" from the page with the link above, here it is. for html and Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //        $('#list').innerhtml = localStorage.getItem("List");


  //$('#incomplete-tasks').html("<P>I just replaced your stuff.</P>");
  $("#Sumbit_Button").click(function() {
    var textbox_Value = $("#textbox").val();
    $('#incomplete-tasks').append('<li><span class="text" contenteditable="false">' + textbox_Value + "</span>" +
      '<input/ style="display: none" class="new-value">' +
      "<button type='button' class='delete'>Delete</button>" +
      "<button type='button' class='edit'>Edit</button></li>");
  });
  $('#incomplete-tasks').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    console.log('i am clicked.delete');
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

  $('#incomplete-tasks').on('click', '.edit', function() {
    console.log("complete task click.edit");
    $(this).siblings('input').show();
    $(this).siblings('.delete').hide();
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $('#incomplete-tasks').on('click', '.edit', function() {
    console.log("INcomplete task click.edit");
    $(this).siblings('input').show();
    $(this).siblings('span').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.delete').hide();
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $('#incomplete-tasks').on('keyup', '.new-value', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      console.log("Complete Task _Version 2.new_value");
      $(this).siblings('span').text($(this).val()).show();
      $(this).siblings('input').hide();
      $(this).siblings('.delete').show();
      $(this).siblings('.edit').show();
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });

  $('#incomplete-tasks').on('click', '.text', function() {
    var li = $(this).parent().remove().toggleClass("strikethrough");
    $('#complete-tasks').append(li);
  });
  $('#complete-tasks').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    console.log('i am clicked.delete');
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

  $('#complete-tasks').on('click', '.edit', function() {
    console.log("complete task click.edit");
    $(this).siblings('input').show();
    $(this).siblings('.delete').hide();
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $('#complete-tasks').on('click', '.edit', function() {
    console.log("INcomplete task click.edit");
    $(this).siblings('input').show();
    $(this).siblings('span').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.delete').hide();
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $('#complete-tasks').on('keyup', '.new-value', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      console.log("Complete Task _Version 2.new_value");
      $(this).siblings('span').text($(this).val()).show();
      $(this).siblings('input').hide();
      $(this).siblings('.delete').show();
      $(this).siblings('.edit').show();
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
  $('#complete-tasks').on('click', '.text', function() {
    var li = $(this).parent().remove().toggleClass("strikethrough");
    $('#incomplete-tasks').append(li);
  });



  //  var save()
  //{
  //      localStorage.setItem("List", $("#list").innerhtml());
  //    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>The Reminder list</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="css/heroic-features.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">To Do List</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Jumbotron Header -->
    <header class="jumbotron hero-spacer">
      <h1> The Reminder Friend App </h1>
      <p>this is my to do list app. type in the list you want to add & store in the list
      </p>

      <form>

        <!-- textbox -->
        <input type="text" id="textbox">

        <!--add button -->
        <input type="button" id="Sumbit_Button" value="Add">


      </form>
    </header>




    <hr>
    <div id='lists'>
      <!-- Page Features -->
      <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
              <h3>Incomplete</h3>
              <ul id="incomplete-tasks">

              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
          <div class="thumbnail">

            <div class="caption">
              <h3>Complete</h3>
              <ul id="complete-tasks">

              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <hr>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <p>Copyright &copy; Mauricio Cuervo 2017</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>


<script src="p4.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: you can use localstorage like: `// Set localStorage item
localStorage.setItem('dataObject', data);` and retreive: `// Retrieve the object from localStorage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('dataObject');` documentation: [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: let me try that, but if you can show it like the format below, that would be helpful thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hello you can do something like this:

```
$("#Sumbit_Button").click(function() {
    var textbox_Value = $("#textbox").val();
    var list = [];
    list.push(textbox_Value);
    localStorage.setItem("listdata", list);

    // do not manage using `append` whole html. Manage through list and display as you want
  });
```

on page load call:

```
var stored = localStorage.getItem("listdata");
```

Now here you can manage array of items and iterate on complete & incomplete list.

So whenever any action of edit, delete, add occurs you have to just manage the localstorage instance on each call. and based on that just iterate list whereever you want.

Comment: So i see what your coming from. Tell me if I'm saying this right

* So back in my js when i edit this in, every time I click the button on the submit box, this will save the data. and you want me to remove the append.*

the only thing i dont get is how to show the button when I remove append. Cause once I remove append, the span with all the button will disappear.  I know u say use display and list, but how do you use it in my case? trying to picture it

PS: where do I put var stored = localStorage.getItem("listdata");? because im trying to understand that last part you wrote. Thank you